# Access database Connection string error in asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have created an asp feedback web page this page connect with the access database
when I run this page every thing is ok until I click to submit button
When I click submit button it gives error like

and here is my asp code

```
<%   
DIM objConn
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.ConnectionString =Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
 Data Source="Server.MapPath("/MyData.mdb")

objConn.Open
%>
<%
DIM objRS
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.Open "tblContact",objConn,adLockOptimistic,adCmdTable
objRS.AddNew
objRS("Email") = Request.Form("Email")
objRS("FirstName") = Request.Form("FirstName")
objRS("LastName") = Request.Form("LastName")
objRS("Comments") = Request.Form("Comments")
objRS("DateContacted") = Date()
objRS.Update
%>

<%
DIM strFirstName
strFirstName = Request.Form("FirstName")
%>

<%
objRS.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
objCONN.Close
Set objCONN = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Please post the error message you get.

Comment: error message isError Type:
Microsoft VBScript compilation (0x800A0401)
Expected end of statement
/Form_ac.asp, line 6, column 55
objConn.ConnectionString = PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("MyData.mdb")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

```
objConn.ConnectionString =Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
 Data Source="Server.MapPath("/MyData.mdb")
```

with

```
objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("/MyData.mdb")
```

Comment: i have one new error "Could not find installable ISAM. at line 5" what is this exactly

Comment: @Rameez: See http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-solve-could-not-find-installable-isam-errors.html and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805